# How to close a vertex AI chat session?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I am creating a chat session, conducting a series of automatic requests but I can't find a way using the python API to close the session in order to initiate another and not leave the context alive.

I am creating the session using:

```python
    chat_model = GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
    chat_model.start_chat()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The context is purely stored locally on your system where the code is running.

The easiest way to initiate a new session is to create a new model with `GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')` again.